# How do I use a loop to iterate through a dictionary that contains lists, calculate something, and add the result to the dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration, population

I'm building a dictionary that has years (key), and a list as the value [population data, 0, 0]
I was able to write a loop to add years as the dictionary keys (1950 to 1990), and import population data from a file to add as [value[0], ...]

**Right now, value[1] and value[2] are empty.**

How do I write a loop that iterates through my dictionary (**starting at index 1, not 0**), calculates the population change, and puts that in value[1] ...for every item in my dictionary?
(*After, I will put percent change in value[2]*)

> myDict = {'1950':[141902, 0, 0],
> '1951':[157311, 0, 0],
> '1952':[186006, 0, 0],
> .... }  # etc. population data from a file object
>
> dict_key = [1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, ... ]  # 41 values total, to 1990

What I have so far:

> def calculate_population_change(myDict, dict_key):
>
> ```
> for i in range(1, (len(dict_key))):
>     value[i] = 7
>     myDict[key[i]] = [value[i], 0, 0]
>
> return myDict
> ```

I wrote value[i] = 7 as a test, to see how to put something in that spot

Thank you for taking a look.

The rest of the code is at, if you need more context: https://github.com/alexisabadger/pythonDictionaryAndList/blob/main/PopulationDataCounter.py

Comment: A list might be a more appropriate data structure choice than a dictionary, for this.

Comment: I was trying lists to start with but I don't know how to iterate through them. Meaning if I have a list of lists, how do I replace the 2nd item in every list within the list?

Comment: ...with a value calculated from other list values?

Comment: You could iterate over the indices of the list, so that you can access an element and the one after it. Have you tried working through things on paper, writing pseudocode, etc.?

Comment: myList = [[year0, population0, 2nd_item, 3rd_item], [year1, population1, 2nd_item, 3rd_item], ... etc.] ...for years = 1950 through 1990

Comment: 2nd_item needs to contain gross_population_change from previous year. So gross_population_change1 = population1 - population0.

Comment: How do I do this? How does one use a loop to grab the 2nd item...in each list, starting with the 1st list (not 0th)... and put in this calculated value gross_population_change?

Comment: I have. I'll try again on paper tomorrow. I know what I want to put where... I just don't know how to get there.

Comment: How do you iterate over the indicates of a list? "In this big list, for each list within it, in spot 2 put this calculated value." (and in spot 3, make it a percentage)

Comment: _How do you iterate over the indicates of a list?_ Have you done any research? You should take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/.

Comment: I have, yes. I've read that. I've looked a number of books. I'm midway through a Python course. I can iterate over the index of one list. It when I have a list within a list, that's what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: I was able to iterate through a list to populate my dictionary with year and population data. I just don't know how to add calculation data (that references multiple values in the list).

Comment: _It when I have a list within a list, that's what I'm having trouble with._ It's really no different, don't overthink it! Try writing building up a solution slowly, visualizing the execution of the code each time you add something.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your dictionary with a foor loop and since your keys represent an ascending number stored as a String, you can convert the sting to an integer, substract one and convert that to a string again in order to get the list of the year before.

```
for year in myDict:
    if year != '1950':
        #Calculate the difference in population of two consecutive years.
        myDict[year][1] = myDict[year][1]-myDict[str(int(year)-1)][1]

        #Calculate the difference as a percentage
        myDict[year][2] = (1-myDict[year][1]/myDict[str(int(year)-1)][1])*100
```